# Проверка файла, пересылаемого пользователем

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Через post-форму в админке пользователи загружают изображения и флэшки на сайт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно надежно ограничить выбор файлов только изображениями и флэш в целях защиты от вирусов.

Comment: [проверка загружаемого файла][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/158986/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте массив допустимых типов и сравнивайте с типом загружаемого файла: **$_FILES['userfile']['type']**

Comment: что мне мешает изменить тип и спокойно заливать исполняемый файл?

Comment: А что мне мешает изменить расширение файла и спокойно загрузить его?

Comment: И что дальше будет? я переименую php в jpg. Что дальше? Он исполнится?

Comment: Я сделаю так, что исполнится. Но курсы хакерства проводить не собираюсь. Только дам вам намек, чтоб не быть голословным. К примеру, если бы я подключил где-нибудь include_once('some_file.jpg');, в котором? ну скажем, <script>alert();</script> , то скрипт выполниться. Это если что...

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, я поржал. Если бы include был, это уже другая история была бы. Я бы вообще тогда из танка в дом пальнул. Жду ваши чудесные курсы.

Comment: Спасибо всем, получается, нет надежного способа определить тип файла?

Answer (score 0):

Про флэш не скажу, про картинку можно решать "в лоб" - [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php):

```
$s = getimagesize($path); 
if (!$s or empty($s[0])) echo 'fail'; // данные получить не удалось или ширина == 0
```

Если на хостинге подключен libswf - можно юзать какие-то функции из него.

Comment: но ведь для getimagesize файл уже должен быть на сервере

Comment: @Mariya так поставьте ограничение на размер файла :-) Залили файл, проверили. Если не изображение - то удалили.

Comment: да, с помошью пхп файл можно проверить только ПОСЛЕ закачки на сервер.

для того чтобы проверить ДО -- ищите либо Flash загрузчик либо библиотеки под яваскрипт.